# How to correct an AD script in power shell

Tags: powershell

I make this script. This script counts how many users have each OU into the two Principal OU's ( **RDS Funcional**  and **VDI Funcional**). The script works fine but i need to remove the total count of this two principals OU's. In the Image wants to remove the line **RDS Funcional,"723"**. There an other line with this **VDI Funcional,"295"**

I need to remove both lines

Also remove the double quotes

Exemple in the image This line is fine -> **4127 Transportes Corporativos,16**

Thanks :)

```
 $log = @()
      "OU=RDS Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc","OU=VDI Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | ForEach-Object {
          Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase $_ | ForEach-Object {
              $log += "Processsing {0}" -f $_.distinguishedname   
             [array] $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -notlike 'test*' -and Name -notlike 'adm*'" -SearchBase $_.distinguishedname
              if ($users -ne $null) {
                  $log += "{0} has {1}" -f $users.name, $users.count
                  [PSCustomObject]@{
                      OU    = $_.name
                      Users = "{0}" -f $users.count
                  }
               }
          }
      } | Export-Csv -Path c:\\ExportUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
      $log
```

Example in that Image:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHC5S.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want the content of selected OU, but only 1st level children OU :

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * -SearchBase $_
```

Comment: How can do this fix?

I use your sentence but prints the same list :(

Thx!

Best

Comment: "4217 Transportes Corporativos" or "3245 Magervysa" are child OU of the main OU "RDS Funcional" ?

Comment: Yes there are many sub OU'd from the two main OU's RDS "Funcional" and "VDI Funcional"

Comment: I changed my answer, "-SearchScope Subtree" if for selected ou and all the children OU